# Black Texture in UV Mode

Tags: uv-image-editor

I have a problem in UV mode.

This is what I have
[image: This is what I have]

This is how should be to look
[image: This is how should be to look]

One of My friend have same version of Blender 2.79b like Me and for him is work fine..

(I have Rx 480 8GB , Win 10)
[image]

Comment: Maximum draw type? (see object property in the "display" section)

Comment: Hi lemon! Maximum Draw Type: Textured

Comment: Can you edit your question adding your blend file? Please use this link to do it http://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/. And... I don't think that's the point, but your texture is "berrel" not "barrel"... just a mistake in the name or other consequence?

Comment: I've downloaded your file. The material for the barrel object is 'wood' and 'ring' and they are not textured (see the material object property). Change the rendered method to 'material' to see that in the 3D view.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This worked for me:

1. Go to face mode, and select one face.

[image: select face]

2. On the UV map side, the texture disappeared, this is fine.

[image: uv map]

3. Hit the A key to select all the faces

[image: select all faces]

4. select the uv map

[image: assign uv map]

5. Texture showed after I did that

[image: result]